# Error al querer convertir un int a una tuple en python

Tags: python

```
def negativo_grises(im):
    tiempoIn = time.time()
    ruta = ("C:/Users/HardSoft/Desktop/Imagenes/" +im)
    im = Image.open(ruta)
    im.show()
    im6 = im
    i = 0
    while i < im6.size[0]:
        j = 0
        while j < im6.size[1]:
            gris = im6.getpixel((i,j))
            valor = 255 - gris
            im6.putpixel((i,j), valor)
            j+=1
        i+=1
    im6.show()
    tiempoFin = time.time()
    print('El proceso tardo: ', tiempoFin - tiempoIn, 'segundos')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Si tu imagen no tiene cada pixel definido por un solo valor ([modos `l` o `L`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes)) `Image.getpixel` va a retornar una tupla con el valor de cada canal, por ejemplo `(100, 100 ,125, 255)` en *RGBA* (valores de cada canal). Lo mismo pasa con *RGB*, *CMYK*, *YCbCr*, *LAB* o *HSV*.

Teniendo en cuanta lo anterior, no puedes restar una tupla a un entero como dice el error. Tienes varias opciones dependiendo de lo que busques, una opción que te va a funcionar pero que es un poco fuerza bruta es convertir la imagen al modo `L` o `l` directamente:

```
imgray = img.convert('L')
```

Tres observaciones importantes:

- Usar un `while` es poco "pitónico" y además es considerablemente más ineficiente que un `for` para iterar sobre la imágen.
- Cuando haces `im6 = im` **no estas creando una copia de la imagen**, simplemente asignas el identificador im6 la referencia del objeto al que apunta `im`. Ambos identificadores apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria (a la misma imágen). Esto implica que cuando modificas `im6` mediante `putpixel` también modifica `im` (en realidad ambas son la misma). Para realizar una copia haz `im6 = im.copy()`
- Para invertir la imágen la forma que usas no es la más eficiente (`putpixel` por lo general no lo es). Por ejemplo [`ImageChops.invert`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.invert) hace esto mismo:

  ```
  from PIL import Image, ImageChops

  im = Image.open(ruta)
  ImageChops.invert(img.convert('L')).show()
  ```

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
import time
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageChops



def negativo_grises(im):
    tiempoIn = time.time()
    ruta = os.path.join("D:\Reproductor", im)
    img = Image.open(ruta)
    print(img.mode)
    imgray = img.convert('L')

    for i in range(imgray.size[0]):    
        for j in range(imgray.size[1]):
            imgray.putpixel((i,j), 255 - imgray.getpixel((i,j)))

    print('El proceso tardo: {} segundos.'.format(time.time() - tiempoIn))

    img.show()
    imgray.show()

negativo_grises("ejemplo.png")
```

Si quieras aplicar la misma transformación a cada canal de un imagen RGB por ejemplo podrías hacer:

```
pixel = tuple(255 - ch for ch in imgray.getpixel((i,j)))
imgray.putpixel((i,j), pixel)
```

Si se va a trabajar intensivamente con los pixeles de la imagen puede ser mejor pasarla a un array NumPy y vectorizar las operaciones en lo posible.